# Windowed Functions in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, window-functions, sql-server-2014

Does anyone know if you can use window functions in a set statement in SQL Server 2014?

I am trying to set a column in an existing table to a count of results from another table.
I can do this with temp tables, just thought it would be cleaner with a windowing function.

```
Update #Totals
  Set 
    TotalContacts = Count(C.PatientID) Over (Partition By C.HospCode)
  From
  #Totals as T
  Inner Join
  #Contacts as C
  On
  T.HospCode = C.HospCode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

SQL Server 2014 doesn't allow windowed functions to be used directly in the `set`. This would not be standard SQL.

Since 2005 you have been able to do this though.

```
WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT TotalContacts, 
                Count(C.PatientID) 
                  OVER (Partition BY C.HospCode) AS Cnt
         FROM   Totals AS T 
                INNER JOIN Contacts AS C 
                        ON T.HospCode = C.HospCode) 
UPDATE CTE 
SET    TotalContacts = Cnt
```

Comment: Yeah- know I can do it that way.  Was just hoping.  Oh well.  Just trying to keep my temp tables and CTEs down to a minimum since already have quite a few in this query.

Comment: @SASUSMC CTEs are just logical/syntactic construct. The execution plan won't be any different than if your hypothetical desired syntax was valid.